# Azure Blob video is not streaming

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to stream my videos from Azure blob, but its not working actually. I checked through different sources and found something interesting to update the `x-ms-version`.

But before doing that I checked it in cloudberry explorer, it says as below.

[image: cloudberry explorer]

But in browser it says `x-ms-version` as 2009 like below

[image: x-ms-version]

Anyway I tried updating the `x-ms-version` using `setBlobProperties` (Azure PHP SDK) but still its not updating. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access set to all on your blob storage container?

[More info here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/)

By default, only the owner of the storage account may access storage resources within that account. If your service or application needs to make these resources available to other clients without sharing your access key, you have the following options for permitting access:

You can set a container's permissions to permit anonymous read access to the container and its blobs. This is not allowed for tables or queues.

You can expose a resource via a shared access signature, which enables you to delegate restricted access to a container, blob, table or queue resource by specifying the interval for which the resources are available and the permissions that a client will have to it.

You can use a stored access policy to manage shared access signatures for a container or its blobs, for a queue, or for a table. The stored access policy gives you an additional measure of control over your shared access signatures and also provides a straightforward means to revoke them.